# MySQL: Aggregate weekly statistics with substatics (subqueries)

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I would like to gather weekly statics on a MySQL-Table.

The table itself has the following structure:

```
user_id         action_id        created
   0              123       2017-01-01 00.00:00
   0              124              ...
   1              123              ...
  ...             ...              ...
```

I would like to aggregate the weekly statics for:

- **How many user where active per week**

  This is rather simple:

  ```
  SELECT 
    YEARWEEK(created) as week, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS count 
  FROM data 
  GROUP BY YEARWEEK(created);
  ```

  Additionally I could apply a sorting.

  The result looks like:

  ```
   week       count
  201701        2
  201702        3
  ```
- **How many user where active per week for the very first time**
  I thought about solving it by using a subquery

  ```
  SELECT 
    YEARWEEK(created) as week, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS count,
    (
      SELECT 
        COUNT(DISTINCT d2.user_id)
      FROM data d2
      WHERE YEARWEEK(d2.created) = week
      AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM data d3
      WHERE YEARWEEK(d3.created) < week AND d2.user_id = d3.user_id)
    ) as countNewUsers
  FROM data d1
  GROUP BY YEARWEEK(created);
  ```
- **How many *junior user* where active per week**
  Junior users were active between 1 and 10 times before the related week
  Similar to the one above, but with other subquery
- **How many *power user* where active per week**
  Senior users were active more than 10 times before the related week

This works as expected, but has a rather poor performance, since the subquery is evaluated before the grouping happens. With millions of rows in a table, this takes ages.

Does anybody have a better solution for this query, ideally returning all values in single result set?

Comment: Rather impossible to help without definitions of junior and power users.

Comment: try with CTE instead of using subqueries... Just an opinion

Comment: Justed clarified the definition of junior and senior users. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

I think all of your queries could derive from one 'intermediate' table.  It would contain (yearweek, userid, count).

- Users active per week:  Pretty much the same query, but faster from this table.
- Active for first time:  Self-join ON userid and desired week versus MIN(yearweek)
- Uses *before* the target week: `... SUM(count) WHERE ... < week GROUP BY userid`
- Use the above to determine which userids of Junior/Power.